# disable editable fields in Tree View Odoo 14

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to make in this tree view the fields read only, but this view is inherited from `hr.employee`, and we are using `<xpath>`, and I am able to make the normal fields read only except for the TITLE and ASSIGNED TO columns

Or is it possible to disable that out of the box checkbox from Odoo 14?
Thanks!!

***View definition:***

```
<record id="view_task_tree_rw" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">project.task.tree.inherited</field>
      <field name="model">project.task</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_tree2"/>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//tree[1]/field[@name='name']" position="after">
          <field name="status"/>
          <field name="date_start" widget="date"/>
          <field name="date_end" widget="date" />
          <field name="billable"/>
          <field name="utilization"/>
          <field name="planned_hours"/>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='company_id']" position="replace"/>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='activity_ids']" position="replace"/>
         <xpath expr="//field[@name='tag_ids']" position="replace"/>

        <xpath expr="//field[@name='stage_id']" position="replace"/>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='project_id']" position="replace"/>
        <xpath expr="//tree[1]/field[@name='name']" position="after">
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='user_id']" position="move"/>
        </xpath>
      </field>
</record>
```

***Screenshot:***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in `xpath` definition you could use `position="attributes"` to override an existing field attributes of the inherited view. so your code would be as following:

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='TARGET FIELD NAME']" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 1):

Method write by @kerbose is ok, but sometimes when there is many inherits to model and you don't know which is last and some field overwrite your field you can just use priority. The default value of priority is 16. So use more higher value because maybe in future you wanna load something between your view and previous view.

Example:

```
<field name="priority">50</field>
```

Sample view:

```
<record id="view_task_tree_rw_inherit_something" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">project.task.tree.inherited.inherit.something</field>
  <field name="model">project.task</field>
  <field name="priority">50</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_tree2"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='TARGET FIELD NAME']" position="attributes" 
     <attribute name="readonly">1</attribute>
    </xpath>

  </field>
 </record>
```